# python -V >> logfile.txt What is needed to make this work?

Tags: python

This command does not work as expected:

```
$ python -V >> logfile.txt
```

The python version is displayed on screen, but does not end up in the logfile, what is needed to get it into the logfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ python -V 2>> logfile.txt
```

`python -V` writes to stderr instead of stdout that's why you must append your append operator with 2.

Comment: @Johnny5 feel free to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

the -V output is going to `stderr`, so you need to redirect it like this:

`python -V 2>> logfile.txt`